# Differentiate Google shopping orders

Tags: google-analytics

Is there an easy way to "flag" all orders that are created due to a Google shopping click?  E.g. set an attribute to 1 where orders had come via Google shopping?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check out this link first before touching any magento core

[Google Shopping Feed in Magento](https://paulnrogers.com/step-by-step-guide-to-setting-up-a-google-shopping-feed-in-magento/)